# Why does `optarg` not get overwritten?

Tags: c, getopt

I am new to `getopt(3)` and looked at some examples and came across [this one](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt).

These lines

```
  case 'c':
    cvalue = optarg;
    break;
```

looked weird to me because the content of optarg does not get copied into `cvalue`, they're just copying the pointer. But it works:

```
$ testopt -a -b -c foo
aflag = 1, bflag = 1, cvalue = foo
```

I expected `optarg` to be overwritten by a second call to `getopt()`, so I wrote my [own program](https://pastebin.com/raw/YjLNiqGT) based on the example. Surprisingly, `optarg` does not get overwritten.

```
$ testopt -p -f me -t you
pflag = 1, from = me, to = you
```

Does this work consistently or should I always copy/duplicate?
Do I have to take care of `free()`ing everything returned in `optarg`?
Am I just getting lucky and the `realloc()` of `optarg` doesn't allocate to the same address?

Comment: I don't see `getopt` anywhere? Did you forget to post the code?

Comment: It's good that you're thinking about the distinction between a pointer and the data to which it points.  But remember that one of the uses of pointers is exactly to avoid copying around data.  Setting `cvalue = optarg` preserves in `cvalue` a *pointer* to the same thing `optarg` pointed to at the time of the assignment.  As long as that isn't changed out from under (and `getopt()` does not do that), `cvalue` will continue to point to the wanted data, no matter what happens to the `optarg` pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [GNU manuals](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html):

> If the option has an argument, getopt returns the argument by storing it in the variable optarg. You don’t ordinarily need to copy the optarg string, **since it is a pointer into the original argv array**, not into a static area that might be overwritten.

That's why it doesn't need to copied or allocated. [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) requires this for `optarg`.

Answer (score 2):

`optarg` points an element in `argv`.  If you can guarantee that `argv` isn't going away or getting touched by any other parts of the code, you should be good. Since `argv` is typically around from the start of `main` to the end of the program, you can safely cache these pointers.

But treat the `optarg` value as `const char*`.  That is, don't try to do anything with this memory other than reference it or copy the original string. Attempting to do something like `strcat` on a pointer is unsafe at best.

Comment: `optarg` could also be a pointer into the interior of an `argv` element, but that doesn't really change much about this answer.